# how to solve the problem about "oracle filesystem is full"?

Tags: oracle10g

When I try to connect oracle database under Linux,it throws errors like this:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-09817: Write to audit file failed.
Linux Error: 28: No space left on device
ORA-09945: Unable to initialize the audit trail file
Linux Error: 28: No space left on device
```

df command shows there's no space left and the filesystem is full.I want to know the size of each tablespace and how to release the free tablespace.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First see which partition is full:

```
# df -h
```

Oracle needs to write to the audit file whenever someone logs on.
Free some space and add a monitor on the mountpoint to alert you before it runs out of space.

I recommend NAGIOS for free monitoring of Linux (and a lot more).